# Clear session storage data with retrieving the specified session storage item

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

I have to clear the session with retrieving the specific item.

there are lot of session items to clear but apart from one cart item

now i am doing like this to retrieve the cart value in session storage

```
var cart = window.sessionStorage.getItem('cart');
window.sessionStorage.clear();
window.sessionStorage.setItem('cart', cart);
```

for it's working fine, now i have to retrieve 7 different items (there are more than 40 session items present in my session),

is there any good way to achieve the same?

*Note: i have only retrieve items keys like ['cart' 'user' 'logTime'] but not clear item keys*

Answer (score 1):

You can create array of keys what you want to remove

```
['key1', 'key2'].forEach((key) => {
  window.sessionStorage.removeItem(key)
});
```

if your list is to big you can create separate variable with all keys
const storageKeys = ['key1', 'key2', etc...]; and storageKeys.forEach(....

Editing according to last comments

```
const savedData = []; 
['key1', 'key2'].forEach((key) => { 
  savedData.push([key, window.sessionStorage.getItem(key)]); 
}); 
window.sessionStorage.clear(); 
savedData.forEach(([key, value]) => window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value));
```

Comment: instead of remove keys, can we achieve by retrieve value keys hence because there are 40+ remove keys ??

Comment: Yes, do this same process to create another array sith property and value, then clear all sessionStorage.

Comment: Yes, all what you have to do is replace `.removeItem(key)` to `.setItem(key, '')`

Comment: sure, const savedData = []; ['key1', 'key2'].forEach((key) => {
  savedData.push([key, window.sessionStorage.getItem(key)]);
});
window.sessionStorage.clear();
and savedData.forEach(([key, value]) => window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
)

Comment: @FahDev i have clear those value not to set as empty string, because it may cause some problem in my code later

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to retrieve the desired session storage item and remove only that specific item, and not the entire storage:

```js
function getStorageItem(itemKey) {
  let item = window.sessionStorage.getItem(itemKey);
  window.sessionStorage.removeItem(itemKey);
  return item;
}
```